How can I group the age with a month and year column?
I have to evaluate my data for my paper with RStudio. I want to group the age like following:
"under 18" ,
"18-25"
"26-35"
"36-45"
"46-55"
"56-65"
"66-75"
"76 and older"
The date on which the data was collect was in June/July 2024. I have one column with month and one with year of the 227 participants. Can someone help me with a code, how I can calculate and group the age with the month and year columns?
I asked Chat GPT and it gave me this. But when I run it, it says "mistake in if (year > 2006 || (year == 2006 && month > 7)) { : missing value, where TRUE/FALSE is necessary". I don´t know if this code makes sense.
current_Jahr <- 2024
current_Monat <- 7

Groups <- list(
  "under 18" = c(2006, Inf),
  "18-25" = c(1998, 2006),
  "26-35" = c(1988, 1998),
  "36-45" = c(1978, 1988),
  "46-55" = c(1968, 1978),
  "56-65" = c(1958, 1968),
  "66-75" = c(1948, 1958),
  "76 and older" = c(-Inf, 1948)
)

function_age <- 
  function(year, month, current_year, current_month) {
  if (year > 2006 || (year == 2006 && month > 7)) { 
    return("under18")
  } else if (year > 1998 || (year == 1998 && month > 7)) {
    return("18-25")
  } else if (year > 1988 || (year == 1988 && month > 7)) {
    return("26-35")
  } else if (year > 1978 || (year == 1978 && month > 7)) {
    return("36-45")
  } else if (year > 1968 || (year == 1968 && month > 7)) {
    return("46-55")
  } else if (year > 1958 || (year == 1958 && month > 7)) {
    return("56-65")
  } else if (year > 1948 || (year == 1948 && month > 7)) {
    return("66-75")
  } else {
    return("76 and older")
  }
}

Age_groups <- mapply(function_year, age$year, age$moth, 
                       MoreArgs = list(current_year, current_month))


We don't need any extra libraries/packages, it can be easily done with base R. I changed your intervals, as they didn't make much sense with age being a continuous measure. (if someone's 25 years and six months old, what group should they be in?). I made it so alle the groups are closed on the left. 25-35 means [25,35), that is, from, and including 25, up to, but not including, 35.
# Example data

set.seed(1)
n <- 20
id0 <- apply(do.call(expand.grid, rep(list(LETTERS), 3)), 1, paste, collapse=".")
dtf <- data.frame(
  id=sample(id0, n), 
  year=sample(1930:2023, n, rep=TRUE),
  month=sample(1:12, n, rep=TRUE)
)


# Define the date age will be calculated to
now <- as.Date("2024-07-01")

# Covert year and month to Date format, assuming medio of each month
dtf$date <- as.Date(with(dtf, paste(year, month, "15", sep="-")))

# Calculating number of years between date and now
dtf$age <- as.numeric((now - dtf$date)/365.24)

# Dividing age into groups
dtf$agegroup <- cut(
  x=dtf$age, 
  breaks=c(0, 18, 15 + (1:6)*10, Inf),
  labels=c("under 18", "18-25", "25-35", "35-45", "45-55", "55-65", "65-75", "75 and older"),
  right=FALSE
)

dtf
#       id year month       date       age     agegroup
# 1  M.X.G 2017    10 2017-10-15  6.710656     under 18
# 2  O.R.J 1949     8 1949-08-15 74.879531        65-75
# 3  F.X.O 1991    10 1991-10-15 32.712737        25-35
# 4  V.P.X 1941     7 1941-07-15 82.964626 75 and older
# 5  H.G.F 1955     7 1955-07-15 68.965612        65-75
# 6  D.J.X 1966    10 1966-10-15 57.712737        55-65
# 7  J.O.Y 1931     1 1931-01-15 93.461833 75 and older
# 8  N.E.R 1965     6 1965-06-15 59.046107        55-65
# 9  C.J.Q 2011     9 2011-09-15 12.794327     under 18
# 10 T.P.B 1961     9 1961-09-15 62.794327        55-65
# 11 E.J.F 1975     6 1975-06-15 49.047202        45-55
# 12 H.P.E 1986    11 1986-11-15 37.627314        35-45
# 13 C.W.R 1976     6 1976-06-15 48.045121        45-55
# 14 M.Z.J 1947     3 1947-03-15 77.299858 75 and older
# 15 Z.Z.T 2007     1 2007-01-15 17.459752     under 18
# 16 E.Y.M 1992     2 1992-02-15 32.375972        25-35
# 17 R.Q.S 2004     4 2004-04-15 20.211368        18-25
# 18 W.T.Z 1940     7 1940-07-15 83.963969 75 and older
# 19 Q.W.J 1998     8 1998-08-15 25.878874        25-35
# 20 Z.E.U 1968     5 1968-05-15 56.130216        55-65


The assumed inputs are shown in the Note at the end.
The yearmon class represents year and month internally as year + 0/12 for January, year + 1/12 for February, ..., year + 11/12 for December so calculate the current year/month as a yearmon object and the year and month in the age data frame as a yearmon object, take the difference and drop the fractional (month) part to get the age.  Use cut to form the groups.
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

current_ym <- as.yearmon(paste(current_Jahr, current_Monat, sep = "-"))
age |>
  mutate(age = as.integer(current_ym - as.yearmon(paste(year, month, sep = "-"))),
         age_group = cut(age, breaks, labels))

giving
   year month age age_group
1  1984     1  40     36-45
2  1988     1  36     36-45
3  2014    12   9  under 18
4  1979    12  44     36-45
5  2003     5  21     18-25
6  1982     7  42     36-45
7  1994     7  30     26-35
8  1966     6  58     56-65
9  2001     2  23     18-25
10 1948    10  75     66-75
11 1950     7  74     66-75
12 1968     4  56     56-65
13 1985    10  38     36-45
14 2023     6   1  under 18
15 1941     6  83   over 75

Note
The inputs in reproducible form
current_Jahr <- 2024
current_Monat <- 7
breaks <- c(-Inf, 18-1/12, seq(25, 75, 10), Inf)
labels <- c("under 18", "18-25", "26-35", "36-45", "46-55", "56-65", "66-75", "over 75")
set.seed(31)
age <- data.frame(year = sample(1940:2023, 15, TRUE),
                  month = sample(12, 15, TRUE))


Thank you for your help! But I am confused, where I insert my data frame "Alter" with the collected birth years ("Jahr") and month ("Monat") of my participants. I have 227 participants and the  years vary from 1936-2013.

As per the instructions at the top of the [tag:r] tag home page questions are supposed to provide reproducible input.  Since the question did not do that the answer provided that in the Note at the end. You will have to adapt the answer to whatever you have or adapt your input to correspond to the assumed input ini the Note or else provide a subset of the input you have using dput so we know exactly what you have.
